# Deterministic Functions in DB2

Tags: db2, deterministic, udf

I have a situation where I need to make My Scalar Function Deterministic so that its not executed every time when used in the same query. 
I read and learned that we need to use both

> DETERMINISTIC

as well as

> NO EXTERNAL ACTION

to make the DETERMINISTIC function work so that its not executed everytime in the query. If I am not wrong ? also that the scope of the deterministic behavior is a single query.

The signature of My UDF is as follows :

```
create or replace FUNCTION my_udf(myLIST VARCHAR(1000)) 
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN ATOMIC
< code for making HTTP  servlet call >
END
```

I am using the following query for testing my_udf() function :

```
select my_udf('admin1,admin2'),my_udf('admin1,admin2') from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

But I see that the call to my servlet is being made each time and hence the functions is being executed each time.

I need to know if there is something wrong that I am doing regarding implementation of the DETERMINISTIC functions or having wrong idea about their usage/functionality ?

Answer (score 4):

The query optimizer ultimately decides whether it can "optimize away" calls to a deterministic UDF. However, in your case it doesn't matter, because your function is indeed *not* deterministic and *does* have external action.

Comment: Exactly.  `DETERMINISTIC` tells the query engine it doesn't have to call the function every time.  But it does not guarantee that it won't.   You should include code inside your UDF to cache the input and output and decide for yourself if you need to remake you HTTP servlet call.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said about `DETERMINISTIC` and `NO EXTERNAL ACTION`. Perhaps you can solve the issue by nesting the function call?

```
select x, x
from (
    select my_udf('admin1,admin2') as x
    from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
```